# Include link tags in template tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, google-fonts

Google Font icons are not rendering in my web component. My webcomponent is based on the following template:

```html
<template id="x-widget-template">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,300,0,0" />

    <style>
    ...
    </style>

    <div>
        ...
        <span class="material-symbols-rounded">
            priority_high
        </span>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

For what it's worth, this is how I am copying the template into the component.

```js
const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
shadowRoot.appendChild(document.getElementById("x-widget-template").content.cloneNode(true));
```

Is this an issue with the Shadow DOM? Have I not implemented something correctly? The icon does render if the link tags are placed in the document head, but I'd like to isolate the link tags to the web component, thus I've defined them in the `template`.

Comment: remove the preconnect links and add the stylesheet via @import ?

Comment: Embedding an import (using the icon font href) statement into the stylesheet does not work.